# Can I ask a question on Stack Overflow that I already asked on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

If the question is also suited for Stack Overflow, should I delete it from Code Review if I didn't have any answers on it and ask it on Stack Overflow, or can I keep both alive?

Comment: Before thinking about posting it on Stack Overflow, please make it is [help/on-topic] and fits within the guidelines set out in [ask]. Also, could we see a link to the question?

Comment: @Tiny Giant this is the question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100603/retrieving-assembly-without-dll .I would remove the last sentence though

Comment: ....you posted than an hour ago. Have some patience.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen If it was 1 month old what would be your answer?

Comment: Well, a best-practices question is probably not a good plan, and if your question is "how do I avoid hardcoding a path in C#", Google's pulling up quite a few answers for me.

Comment: That question would be closed as "Primarily Opinion based" in a heartbeat on Stack Overflow. I guess if you removed the "Best practices" part it might pass, but Code Review is still the best place for it. Like @Night said, it was posted an hour ago, give it a few days, maybe post a bounty once that option is available. If it was a month old, you had posted a bounty and still hadn't gotten any answers, I would say remove the best practices part and try it here, but it could still be closed as too broad if someone with more domain knowledge thinks it is.

Comment: I would venture a guess that 99.9% of the time a question cannot be on-topic for *both* Code Review and Stack Overflow. Code reviews are generally off-topic and closed quickly on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commenters make good points- I will not reiterate them, for redundancy's sake.

**Simply put**: YES, it is OK (*but read on*).  I am having trouble finding the link at the moment, but there is a Stack Exchange podcast somewhere in the 50s range (episode 56?  55?) where they say that in some cases the same question is applicable on multiple sites when it will yield totally different answers from the different sites.  So for example, asking:

> What would the implication of the P = PN be on everyday life?

would obviously yield totally different types of answers on the Cryptography, Mathematics and Philosophy Stack Exchanges, respectively (though that example is likely *too broad* for most if not all of those sites). So yes, you could ask the same question on multiple sites, *if* your question is topical to all sites included and *if* the expertise of each respective site would be likely to yield radically different types of answers.

**That said**, you will likely be down voted if discovered as it is not considered good decorum.  [Proof](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)- especially if you post on similar sites (like CodeReview and CodeGolf) which would seem like "cheating" to most.

Comment: Your "proof" is exactly what I was looking for,thanks.

Comment: No worries :) Sorry I couldn't find that podcast link though