# Is it ok to post on code review and SO at the same time?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, code-review-se, cross-posting

I have a [finished piece of code that I submitted on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101339/kosaraju-in-scala). As I did not have had any answer nor comments, I was wondering if it could be a good idea to submit it on SO too.

I'd be glad to know if this question would also fit SO, if it's ok to duplicate in such cases, and the reasons of whatever are the answer (to be a better community member ;).

**edit**: With the same goal of being a better community member, I'd love to know why this question is not appropriate for SO meta (which it seems to be seeing the downvotes).

Not really a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302286/can-i-ask-a-question-on-stackoverflow-that-i-already-asked-on-codereview), as I did **not** know if my question was unfit for SO

Comment: That question would be off-topic on Stack Overflow as Too Broad, or Primarily Opinion Based. Most all code review questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, put it this way, how would you feel if you worked all weekend on developing some software, only to find that someone else had done exactly the same job, delivered it 2 minutes before you and got paid for it, leaving you with nothing?

Comment: I don't get your point Martin, nor do I get the point of downvoting what seems to be a legit question. I think you're right Tiny, tyvm.

Comment: @MartinJames is talking about losing out on your hard work by form of accepted answer on another site.

Comment: It's not clever to post your question on multiple sites to try and reach a greater audience, possibly yielding faster results. In fact, it's down-right annoying to the users of those sites.

Comment: The downvotes don't actually indicate *inappropriateness* of *this* question, but bemoan lack of research-effort and also indicate a "hell no"-response. [What do votes mean on Meta? Why was my well-written post downvoted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918)

Comment: Voting on meta is different. Often it's a signal of disagreement or dislike than it is an indicator of question quality. I'm not saying it's right, it's just how it is.

Comment: I see. That was not really the purpose I was trying to convey. Btw I stumbled on the question you proposed in the duplicate flag, and just found it was not exactly my case. I think I also get what all of you means by the "unfairness" toward people whom answer when posting on different websites.

Comment: Hm. So your question is actually two-in-one: 1. Is this in scope? 2. What about crossposting?

Comment: So, another thin now: As I think I have the answer to this question from the multiple comments, should I close it, or will someone officially answer it? :)

Comment: Right, Deduplicator. I guess this is also something to avoid...

Comment: If you think it might help someone, leave it up and consider self-answering if noone else does so better. Otherwise, kill it. One interesting alternative to answering is finding a dupe for the second part and voting to close (and then accepting) with that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You only posted this question yesterday. Code Review questions take a significant amount of time and effort to answer. I wouldn't stress too much about the question going unanswered until you hit the 2 or 3 day mark and by then...
2. You can always place a bounty on your question to draw in an answer. There usually isn't more than 10 or so bounties on CR at any time, so bountied questions tend to get answers.
3. Some languages have bigger followers than others. Times to answer will vary. If you are in a language that doesn't have a lot of activity, you're highly encouraged to go back and review your own code. You'd be surprised at how effective this is at both improving your code and growing the tag's sub community.
4. This question is far too broad for StackOverflow. There isn't a specific problem to be solved, no minimal example... No. Code Review is definitely the place for this question. (It's actually a pretty good CR question IMO.) An answer to this question would be a blog post by SO standards, but just a run of the mill very long answer by CR standards.
5. Cross posting is generally frowned upon because a good SO question is very different from a good CR question. Although, there may be instances where a question could be asked on multiple sites, it's likely that they would need to be heavily edited and customized for each site to be on topic and good questions.

Answer (score 4):

A small number of questions are indeed on-topic on both sites.  If your question is specific enough to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but open-ended enough to be on-topic for Code Review, then cross-posting is possible.  If you do cross-post, **please declare the cross-posting** with mutual links in the comments on both posts, so as to avoid wasting other users' time when triaging your question.

That said, you should have a better reason for cross-posting than "gimme an answer by any means possible".  For example, it could be that you seek both an answer to a specific question and feedback on all aspects of your code.

Your specific question ([Kosaraju in Scala](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101339/9357)) is too open-ended to be on-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you haven't gotten an answer, posting it again is bad etiquette.  Please stop by the [The 2nd Monitor, the Code Review chat room](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).  It may be that the question was poorly formulated or that it simply didn't receive the proper attention at the time.  Either way, mentioning it in chat can help.

Comment: I actually did not know that chat room. Seems a good idea, +1